# Google map clusteritem click event not working when it above a marker

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm using the android clustering utility on a map and succesffuly implemented an onclick listener with mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener() for the cluster items.

Because I also want some markers to always be unclustered, I also add some markers without using the mClusterManager but directly using the map's mMap.addMarker(), this way I'm sure that they are never clustered on the map.

My problem is that I when a clusterItem or a cluster overlay a marker,the function OnClusterClickListener not work. When i Separate then form each other it work again

Is there a way to solve my problem?

Thank you

Comment: Call the cluster manager in your onMarkerClickListener - there is only one listener possible.

Comment: @Andy that not i ask for, i want OnClusterClickListener call even the cluster item overlay with a marker.